# Exclude characters from REGEX expression

Tags: regex

Regex expression:

```
^[a-z A-Z0-9-/().,@&#*!%:-]{0,100}
```

How can I add an exclusion for the '$' and '+' signs?  I tried the following but it didn't work.  It excluded the first excluded character it came to and every other character after that (including characters I wish to include).

```
^[a-z A-Z0-9-/().,@&#*!%:-][^$+]{0,100}
```

Comment: Check my answer bellow, if it doesnt fit what you want, please add some examples of the input and the expacted output to give you an appropriate answer...

Comment: You are forcing the first 100 characters to be any of these: a-z A-Z0-9-/().,@&#*!%:- So $ and + are already excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead wich checks if the input doesnt contain any `$` or `+`, then selects the appropriate characters:

```
/^(?!.*?[$+])[a-z A-Z0-9-\/().,@&#*!%:-]{0,100}/
```

[`Live DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/rP2aC9)

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [$+]                     any character of: '$', '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z A-Z0-9-             any character of: 'a' to 'z', ' ', 'A' to
  \/().,@&#*!%:-           'Z', '0' to '9', '-', '\/', '(', ')', '.',
  ]{0,100}                 ',', '@', '&', '#', '*', '!', '%', ':', '-
                           ' (between 0 and 100 times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

You already made `$` and `+` sign excluded when didn't include them in your char class:

```
[a-z A-Z0-9\-\/().,@&#*!%:]{0,100}
```

As the way I understood, you don't need `^` to check the beginning of the input. also you'd better to escape `-` as it's in the middle of class and remove the one that's at the end, as well as `/` that may be used as delimiter.

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/gU2iQ0)